# Designing a data model that incorporates logical operators

Tags: database, database-design, plsql, oracle11g, data-modeling

I am new to data modeling and i'm having trouble coming up with a data model that can store logic.

The data model would be used to store location and marketing attributes.

When a customer visits one of the company's websites, they would enter in their zip code, and based on their location the attributes would be used to arrange the online catalog of items.

The catalog of items would be separate from the database, so the data model would only produce the output of attributes used to arrange the items. Each item in the catalog has attributes such as ItemNumber, Price, Condition, Manufacture, and marketing segments (Age:Adult, Education: College, Income:High, etc.).

```
 **For example:** 
 **Input zip code**: 90210
 **Output Attributes**: (ItemNumber:123456, Segment:HighIncome, Condition:New)
```

This example is saying for zip 90210, first show item #123456, followed by all of the items with the HighIncome segment, and then display all of the non-refurbished items.

So far I have 2 tables with a many to many relationship and I would like to add an additional table(s) so I can incorporate logic (AND & OR).

The first table would have location and other information about which of the company's site the user is on.

```
Table Location(
Location_Unique_Identifier number
ZipCode varchar2
State varchar2
Site varchar2
.. 
)
```

The second table would have the attributes types (Manufacture, Price, Condition, etc.) and the attribute values (IBM, 10.00, Refurbished, etc.).

```
 Table  Attributes(
 Attribute_Unique_Identifier number
 Attribute_Type varchar2
 Attribute_Value varchar2
 ..
 ..
 )
```

In-between these two tables to break up the many to many relationship I would add the logic table. This table should allow me to output

```
item#123456  AND  (item#768900 OR Condition:New)
```

The problem I am having with the logic table is trying to make it flexible enough to handle an unknown amount of AND/ORs and to handle the grouping.

Comment: Tables are used to represent facts, not logic.  Logic goes into queries and stored procedures.  Also, don't reinvent a database inside a database (referring to your Attributes table).  EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) tables are usually bad design.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical scenario of JOIN two( many ) tables together to do AND/OR/XOR or something else logical.

The best choice is to build a meterailized view that denormalize the attributes from multiple tables together into one table(this table is called a view).

In your case, the view may be:

```
table location_join_attributes{  
    number, 
    zipcode,  
    state,  
    site, 
    Manufacture, 
    Price, 
    Condition,  
    ......
}
```

Then you will operate your logical statement on this table/view as(modified from your example):

```
item#123456  OR  (item#768900 AND Condition:New) AND (more condition)
```

If we do not have this view, this operation will firstly fetch out all the records have item#768900, and then filter among the second table to know which of them have condition:new. It will take a long time to finish. If the condition is complex, the performance is terrible.

For quick query, you should build secondary indexes on the columns you operate.

On the scalability side, if your business logic changes, you may build a new view, and the older one will be discarded. The original tables do not change, which is also one of the advantages of a materialized view has.